# How to download an image from the web and display it in an UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

How to download an image from the web and display it in an UIImageView? For example, I have an URL like:
http://sstatic.net/so/apple-touch-icon.png

[image]

Would I need to mess around with NSURLConnection and the like, or is there a simple method that takes an web URL and downloads the image data automatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NSData`'s `dataWithContentsOfURL:` class method to download the image data from the server, then just pass that data to `UIImage`'s `imageWithData:`class method.

Here's an example:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://sstatic.net/so/apple-touch-icon.png"]];

UIImage *downloadedImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

myImageView.image = downloadedImage;
```

Comment: is that method working in the background, or does it block the current thread?

Comment: It blocks. If you need asynchronous requests, use `NSURLConnection`

Comment: And how does it handle connection problem ? Returns nil ?